# Set ng-model value from ng-repeat input in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to allow the customer to edit a list of items by using ngRepeat and ngModel. But i am not able to set response to the input fields 
Here is the code.

```
<form name="customerupdateForm" ng-submit="EditCustomerSubmit(updatecustomer)" class="horizontal-form">                             
    <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="updatecustomer in itemList">
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="customer_name" ng-model="updatecustomer.customer_name" class="span6 m-wrap"/>                                          
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="company_name" ng-model="updatecustomer.company_name" class="span6 m-wrap"/>                                            
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Angular.js**

```
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;

$scope.getupdateCustomerdata = function(id){
    $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'api/master/customer/getupdatecustomer?id=' + $routeParams.id
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        console.log(response.data['customer_name']);
        $scope.updatecustomer = {};
        //set response to input filed
        $scope.updatecustomer.customer_name = response.data['customer_name'];
    }); 
}
$scope.getupdateCustomerdata();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are seeing?  From the code that you've posted, it looks like you are performing a `GET` to retrieve some customer data, but the `ng-repeat` is looking at `itemList`, which I don't see defined it your code.

Comment: yes, i have retrieve data  and this  data response set to input field @BrendanGreen

Comment: you want the response data to be set to your input elements?

Comment: yes i want @FakharAhmadRasul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your api is returning you a list of `Customers`, in that case you have to make the api response equal to `itemList` in angularjs

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {

    console.log(response.data['customer_name']);
    $scope.updatecustomer = {};
    //set response to input filed
    $scope.itemList = response;
});
```

if your response is a list of objects and has properties named `customer_name`, `company_name` then your input elements will be populated with the model value